# can't end node.js application through ctrl-c on MAC

Tags: node.js, macos

I am a node.js user for sometime and now this is my first time to work node.js on the mac, in the terminal I tried to end the node.js application server on port 8080 through the ctrl-c, it seemed the application stopped, but when I started the application again, the error 'error: Error: listen EADDRINUSE' throw out.

by using sudo lsof -nP -iTCP:8080-sTCP:LISTEN, I found the node.js server is actually not closed down for some reason by using the ctrl-c. now I have to force close the node.js process through terminal command sudo killall -KILL node.

Could anyone experience the same thing on mac

Answer (score 1):

The socket(s) need to be closed on exit as well.

Try adding the next code to your node application:

```
process.on('SIGINT', function() {
  socket.close();
  process.exit();
});
```

Comment: I did it, but still the same that when I pressed ctrl + z, the program ended and seemed not running into this part of code because I have embed a console output into the SIGINT callback function, nothing outputs

Comment: Ctrl+Z does not end program but **pause** it.

Comment: when I am in linux or windows, that is how I end the program. so what could allow me to end it in mac env?

Comment: Ctrl+C is to terminate. Ctrl+Z is to suspend. (Usually puts application into background and later can be resumed)